# .net 3.5 COM loading 4.5.2 assembly

Tags: c#, .net, com

I have a C++ `exe` file. It created a .Net 3.5 based COM object, which needs to load a .Net 4.5.2 assembly.

I tried creating a manifest file in the COM object project to specify:

```
<clrClass
   name="ComAssembly.MyClass"
   clsid="{67975F17-3D44-38C1-BC2C-B58E50A481F6}"
   runtimeVersion="v4.0.30319.34000"
   threadingModel="Both"
 />
```

but I'm still getting error `8013101b` (assembly is built by a new runtime ...)

How to do it correctly?

Comment: The `runtimeVersion` is not correct, so probably had no effect, use "v4.0.30319".

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the value of the registry RuntimeVersion value for the COM class InprocServer32 and InprocServer32\1.0.0.0.
It works fine with v4.0.30319.34000

Comment: Hmm, no, just don't use a manifest at all when you are going to rely on the registry.  And be sure to use Regasm.exe to get the registry keys correct.  Hacking keys by hand just makes it four times more convoluted and error-prone.